# CSS cursor line size when entering an Input field

Tags: php, css

I have an image as the background for an input field.  I can set the line-height and font-size easily but when you click inside the input, the cursor line is way outside the background image.

Is there a CSS statement (Is that you call them?) that controls this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You're probably using `line-height` to display the text in the input as vertically centered. However, it is also the culprit of your issue. Try experimenting with `padding` settings of the input instead, while leaving the `line-height` set to `normal`.

Comment: I just played around with the height/padding of the input and got it working right.  I was just curious if there was something built into CSS to handle it

Comment: I wish :) Unfortunately not though.

Comment: What if i have same issue for [textarea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760345/line-height-vs-cursor-height-issue-in-textarea-in-chrome)

Answer (score 3):

Problem with using padding is that it is displayed inconsistently in different browsers while line-height in input text areas are displayed equally in `IE7`, `IE8`, `IE9`, `Safari`, `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `Opera`. It's seems like you have to choose between input cursor or input text vertical alignment.

Comment: I experience the same issue of these varying effects across all of the browsers.  I don't have a way to make it perfect in all :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes, **line-height**.

Try:

```
input {height: 28px; font-size: 10px; padding: 7px 5px;}
```

Comment: If you read the question you would see that the OP has already set the `line-height` to something for other style related purposes...

Answer (score 0):

The post [Vertically aligning the text cursor (caret?) in an input box with jQuery, Javascript or CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211078/vertically-aligning-the-text-cursor-caret-in-an-input-box-with-jquery-javascr) may help you.

It seems that your padding size affects the cursor size and position.

Answer (score 0):

Will be good if we have the code , you also can try

```
background:url("yourimage") right top no-repeat;
font-size:12px;
padding:5px 5px;
line-height:normal;
```

depends of your images size

Answer (score 0):

Using a `line-height: normal` or a `line-height:inherit` did the trick on my side.
Thanks for your answers guys.

Answer (score -1):

the text in input tag can be vertical centered automatically, do not use line-height on it.