# line-height vs cursor height issue in Textarea in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can we reduce cursor height same as font-height if we specify line-height greater than font-size. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/creatingawesomestuff/Jqczb/) in Chrome browser and you will get what I am talking about. This works fine in Firefox, issue is only in Chrome browser. 
Textarea html is :

```
<TEXTAREA style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 50px; height: 150px;"></TEXTAREA>
```

EDIT:

I want line-height space between lines as i have background image for textarea with horizontal lines on which i am trying to place the text.

Comment: Did you wan't the text in the middle of the caret?

Comment: You could create a textarea out of a div using jquery and then you would have a lot more flexibility

Comment: This all problem occurred through `line-height` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you want to change the Caret located inside the text area. Here's a post that covers this.

[Styling text input caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339333/styling-text-input-caret)

Answer (score -1):

```
try this for line height space between line...


<div style="background-color: lime; line-height: 2cm;">
testing line height - line 1 <br>
testing line height - line 2 <br>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what the asker wanted. I believe the asker wants to use line-height to increase spacing between lines, but leave the cursor size same as font-size.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried this code in Chrome and it was successful. Now you implement and check your code.

```
<TEXTAREA style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; line-height: 10px; height: 150px;"></TEXTAREA>
```

Comment: The OP wants line-height space between lines.

Comment: Yes i want line height space between lines as i have background image for textarea with horizontal lines on which i am trying place text.

Comment: This is not what the asker wanted. I believe the asker wants to use line-height to increase spacing between lines, but leave the cursor size same as font-size.